# Как сделать компилятор для мобильных устройств

Tags: java, android, c++, компилятор

Как сделать компилятор для мобильных устройств например компилятор по c++, java, html. И что для этого нужно знать?

Comment: Для этого нужно прочитать не одну книгу, начиная с ассемблера и вряд ли вы дойдете до чтения чего то о JAVA

Comment: Dragonbook читайте...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Путь героя выглядит так:

1. Придумайте свою грамматику, ну то есть свой язык (если речь идет о C++, то все *сильно упрощается* поскольку грамматику уже до вас разработали Керниган, Риччи и Страуструп)
2. Далее пишем парсер вашей грамматики - к вашему счастью это уже давно формализовано и доведено до автоматизма - берите `ANTLR` или `yacc` - они переводят формализованную грамматику вашего языка до генератора парсера - то есть разобьют ваши грамматические изыски до токенов, лексем и проч.
3. Далее для лексем и токенов, до которых будет разбит ваш язык пишете машинные коды/инструкции. Типа если есть конструкция `if` это соответствует ассемблерной инструкции `jnz` ну и т.д.
4. Потом собираете линкер, то есть некую аппу, которая разрешает внешние ссылки - привязывает ваш код, в котором есть вызовы внешних библиотек к либам, добавляет необходимые прибамбасы, что получился нормальный *executable* - исполняемый согласно правилам оси файл.
5. В итоге на выходе получаете компилятор в первой итерации (вся процедура называется [bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers))
6. Если применимо (то есть, если бутстраппинг был сделан на самом языке) то получившийся код компилятора компилируете своим компилятором еще раз - [self-hosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-hosting)

Если речь идет об интерпретаторе, то все сильно упрощается и обычно завершается на этапе 2.5 - то есть токены и лексемы доводятся до псевдомашинного кода.

**P.S.** Считаю, что каждый уважающий себя программист, хотя бы раз в жизни должен придумать свой интерпретирующий язык программирования (компилятор это уже излишне - это дело узких профессионалов).